# wordpress select multiple results in plugin category post like style

Tags: wordpress

I am looking at creating a selection pretty similar to the posts and categories in Wordpress admin page.

When you add a new post you can select multiple categories that it belongs too.

I have a video and playlist plugin that I need to associate with one another.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to do this in the database, or in the UI?

In the database, you will need a many-to-many relation table (`video_id`, `playlist_id`).

In the UI, the easy way is to do it like the categories, and display a checkbox before each playlist. If you want it with autocompletion like the tags, you will need some AJAX tricks. You can get inspiration in [`wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php), in the functions `post_tags_meta_box` and `post_categories_meta_box`.

If you can adapt your code to use [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies), you will get all this for free.